# Efficient and correct way to store image data in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

To clarify, I'm having to develop a GUI application that stores information about clients (for a course) where one of the fields is the logo of the client. I'm currently using serialization to persist the information, but in Java BufferedImage cannot be Serialized.

I also cannot merely save the path since this could change for whatever reason.

Is there a good way to achieve persistence with image data using Serialization, or is a database necessary in this situation?

Comment: If you're reading the file in at some point, why not just serialise that?

Comment: Images of any size? Are talking about big and heavy images (MB, GB, etc). If we are speaking about KBs or Bytes, don't think you need a buffer. Unless you manage load of them concurrently.

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is [Java Custom Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290777/java-custom-serialization). So if this is just a coding question, you will find all the answers you are looking for on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that those images are the logotypes of your customers, this means that those images are expected to be rather small, in a range of several hundreds of kilobytes at most. Either they upload their logotype, which usually means a small PNG image, or you are uploading a logotype you created for them, which means a combination of vector images, necessarily small, and a series of PNGs, the largest ones using possibly 1 to 2 MB.

In both cases, you can:

- Either manage the images in-memory as chunks of binary data (and store them accordingly as BLOB).
- Or [if the database you use supports it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), use file stream capabilities to lower the memory footprint (which may be useful if you have to handle hundreds of logotypes at once).
- Or store the images in files, instead of a database. This approach may look easier at first, however you'll quickly realize that it is not, as soon as you'll need to handle backups, versioning, and other aspects which are provided “for free” with any mature relational database system.

Comment: Or store the images in S3 (other blob storage services are available). Backups, versioning and other aspects are now provided for free(-ish).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this more difficult than is needs to be.  There are already so many ways to store images as bytes e.g. JPG, GIF, or PNG.  Surely one of these formats meets your needs.  Most commonly, JPG or PNG (if you need transparency) for something like this.  There's no need to 'serialize' the  ImageBuffer because everything you need to create the image is defined in the JPG or PNG bytes.

If you need to store these in a DB, you can load the bytes into a BLOB field.  If the files are small enough, you might even be able to store them as a Base64 encoded string, if that's your preference.

Unless you are modifying the image in the application somehow, there's no reason to serialize the in memory data of the image.  If everything goes well, you'll simply get something that is equivalent to what you loaded in the first place.

On a side node, Java serialization can challenging to work with and is not very portable.  It's not something I would recommend for a new application.